# Filter on one column, return all related results for a different column

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I've been trying to think of how to do this and can't quite figure it out. The premise is as follows. I need to filter on **COLUMN B**, following that I need to use the filtered returned results of **COLUMN A** to filter all of the results. If that's confusing I tried to 'draw' it out below...

```
COL A | COL B |
cat   | 44    |
cat   | 476   |
cat   | 19    |
dog   | 11    |
dog   | 12    |
bird  | 44    |
bird  | 99    |
bird  | 4556  |
```

So if I filter on Column B for 44 I'll only get the two '44' rows returned (cat | 44 and bird | 44). **Instead**, I want to somehow get all of the cat rows and all of the bird rows, since 44 was associated with those two 'A' types.

```
COL A | COL B |
cat   | 44    |
cat   | 476   |
cat   | 19    |
bird  | 44    |
bird  | 99    |
bird  | 4556  |
```

Have any of you done this before? My idea was initially to copy the unaltered sheet over to a new sheet 2, apply the filter and copy the returned column A results to a new sheet 3, use the returned column A results in sheet 3 to do an autofilter on the sheet2 column A. However, there can be hundreds of filters and this is a pretty manual process in VBA.

I'd be happy to add more detail if needed.

Comment: [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) on *44* then collect the values from column A (.SpecialCells(XlCellTypeVisible) into dictionary keys and apply another autofilter on the array of keys.

Comment: Thanks! Would this be done in a VBA script? Not sure how I would apply an autofilter on an area.

Comment: Since you have declined to show original effort, the only question is what you plan to do with the double filtered data once you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) and [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with one or more variant arrays.

```
Option Explicit

Sub cats_and_birds()
    Dim crit As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iCols As Long
    Dim arr1 As Variant
    Static dict As Object  '<~~ faster second time around this way
    
    'create and configure the static dictionary
    If dict Is Nothing Then _
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.RemoveAll
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    'number of columns to transfer from column A
    iCols = 3
    'set filter criteria for column 2 within range
    crit = 44
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        'assign raw values
        arr1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, iCols).End(xlUp)).Value2
        
        'show the data array limits in the Immediate window
        'delete this or comment it after the routine works
        Debug.Print LBound(arr1, 1) & " to " & UBound(arr1, 1)
        Debug.Print LBound(arr1, 2) & " to " & UBound(arr1, 2)
        
        'iterate through the 'rows' of the array and compare column 2
        For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
            'add/oversrite the pet species as key
            If arr1(i, 2) = crit Then _
                dict(arr1(i, 1)) = 0
            
            'if pet species in key, transfer information
            If dict.exists(arr1(i, 1)) Then
                'iterate through the columns backwards to maintain row
                For j = UBound(arr1, 2) To LBound(arr1, 2) Step -1
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Offset(1, j - 1) = arr1(i, j)
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    
    End With

End Sub
```

This would actually be better with two arrays; the second receiving the results and then bulk transferring the information but there is also a (smaller) penalty due to redim'ming the array with preserve (and transposing). For small (<10K) this is probably only marginally longer to process. For <100 rows of filtered information you might not be able to measure the difference without special tools.

[image]

Dim'ming the dictionary object as Static shortens the load time the second time around because you do not have to recreate the object. While I prefer to add the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** to the Tools ► References and use `dim dict as new scripting.dictionary` not everyone prefers that so I'll post this with CreateObject and dim dict as static.

Answer (score 1):

You can take this routine as a model: it applies to `Sheet1`, looks for `44` in column `B` then shows the rows that match from column `A`

```
Sub filterBthenA()
    Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns("B").AutoFilter 1, 44 '<-- Filter Sheet1 col B by value 44
    Dim cel As Range, dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each cel In Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        dict(cel.Value) = 0
    Next
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns("A").AutoFilter 1, dict.Keys, xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: This would fail if there were two 'cat' entries with '44'. I find it always best to check if `if not dict.exists(cel.Value) then dict(cel.Value) = 0` just to be sure. The OP's sample data was not entirely clear on whether there was a header label to the data which AutoFilter requires. While this is *usually* true, the sample data was not specific enough to guarantee it.

Comment: Hmmm ... maybe I forgot about overwriting the dict.key's value. I will have to test to make sure.

Comment: @Jeeped I tested that case. It wont because the criteria range is the `dict.keys`, no duplicates there.

Comment: As mentioned earler, I think I forot about the add/overwrite method that you used so eloquently.

Comment: @Jeeped Yeah (we posted simultaneously :) ). On another plan, I wish I could pass the `Columns("A").SpecialCells(...)` directly as criteria to the second `.AutoFilter`... This would've made it much shorter, dropping the dico. Couldn't find it. Do you see a way?

Comment: I don't think there is any better way for non-contiguous range. I am guessing that the items in the second filter array don't need to be unique, so maybe another option can be sorting the data and something like `.AutoFilter 1, Application.Transpose(Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)), xlFilterValues`.

Comment: @A.S.H - I threw out AutoFilter completely and relied on arrays. See my response. As mentioned, it would be better with a second array to accept the filtered returns and then bulk transfer back to teh worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for the help all of you. I was able to use the second reply below to get everything to work. Really appreciate it, will try to add more information in the future.